# Is there a way to install Nokia PC Suite onto my netbook?

Tags: phone

I have a Samsung N150 Plus net book which works great with Ubuntu, but can't use Nokia's PC Suite application to keep my Nokia E63 updated? Any ideas please?

Comment: obviously nokia doesnt have a linux version - can I suggest, add to your question, what capabilities/functionality from the PC suite do you want ubuntu to do? e.g. just a mass storage device or sync with something.

Comment: I also have a Nokia phone, however I have looked into the nokia forums and they don't have any linux version of the Nokia PC Suite. However, I've been able to transfer music, pictures and files from and to my mobile through a USB cable. I guess you might lose the functionality of syncing.

Comment: I can use my phone as a storage device etc, my main aim is to get software uploads for the phone, I'm not too worried about anything else really.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [howto on syncing other Nokia E-Series phones with evolution](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2007/09/12/nokia-e-series-sync-with-evolution-via-bluetooth-in-ubuntu/).

The other alternative is to try [installing the Nokia PC Suite under Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=13360), but this is not likely to work very well.

If your computer recognises your phone, you may be able to install and use [kmobiletools](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=15259) to sync your contacts.

If you add some more information about what exactly you need to do, there may be some more specific instructions I can add.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it using wine and failed to make it work properly.Here's a alternative to Nokia PC suite: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nokuntu/

You can do almost everything using "Nokuntu" suite as u did with Nokia PC suite.